# How to recover from running 'cd /var && find ./ -type f -atime 3 -delete'?

Tags: rm, system-restore

I intended to delete files under /tmp, however, I accidently did it under the /var folder with root user. I also stupidly hence run `systemctl restart mysql` :-(
Now mysql service cannot start, and there are many messages in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHJUZ.png)

How to know which files has been deleted and what are the impacts to services and even Ubuntu OS 20.04?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reinstall, restore your backups.

Comment: I would perhaps argue a reinstall is not needed, but boot a live system and restore `/var`...

Comment: @vidarlo Would you pls share me a link of a detailed tutorial?

Comment: I have no idea how you do backups. Server administration in general doesn't lend itself to detailed tutorials. You should know your environment and how to e.g. do disaster recovery.

Comment: Thanks you all. Finally, I sadly gave up.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is possible to recover the files depends on various factors. There are several threads with information on how to recover files.

One option would be to try via `debugfs`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31884665/22177574

If you are using a ext3/ext4 filesystem (Check via: `lsblk -f`) another option would be the `extundelete` tool:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722784/22177574